# Jquery click to scroll for a specific distance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a horizontal list of images in a div. Each image has a width of 60%. I want to display them like this, at a time only 3 images should be visible the first section should only contain 20% of the image, second should contain 60% (Complete) and third should contain 20% of the image. Problem arises when i want to implement this for a large list of images.

So lets say i have 5 images, i want them to be like this first image to be 20%, second to be 60 % and third to be 20%. When the next button is clicked i want the second image to become 20% , 3rd image 60%(Complete) and 4th image to be 20% width and so on.

This is the code that i have come up with

```
   <div class="center" id="content">

             <!--First Image 20%by default--><div id="internal-cover" class="internal" style="width:20%"></div>

             <!--Second Image--><div id="internal" class="internal"></div>

    <!--Third Image--><div id="internal" class="internal"></div>
             <!--fourth Image--><div id="internal" class="internal"></div>
                     <!--Fifth Image--><div id="internal" class="internal" ></div>


    </div>



            <style type="text/css">

            body
            {
            margin: 0px auto;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            }
                /* Put your css in here */



            .internal{
            width: 60%;
            height: 100%;
            background-size:cover; 
            display: inline-block;

            }

            .center{
            float: left; 
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
            /*will change this to hidden later to deny scolling to user*/
            white-space: nowrap;
            }



            </style>
            </body>

            </html>




            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            // Add your javascript here


    var first =0;
            var second = first+1;
            var third= second+1;
            var ctr=0;
            $('#internal-cover').addClass("left-button");

            $(document).on("click",".right-button",function(){
              event.preventDefault();
              //resetSize();
              $('#content').animate({
                scrollLeft: "+=812px"//20%Left 60-40% = 60%of Width

              }, "fast");
     console.log(
    $('.center').scrollLeft()
             );
              first++;
              second++;
              third++;handleSet();
            });

            $(document).on("click",".left-button",function(){

              event.preventDefault();
              //resetSize();
              $('#content').animate({
                scrollLeft: "-=812px"
              }, "fast");

              first--;
              second--;
              third--;
              handleSet();

            });

             function resetSize()
             {
                $('.internal').each(function(){

                        $(this).css("width","60%");

                });
             }
             function handleSet()
             {  

                    console.log(first+"---"+second+"---"+third);
                    $('.internal').each(function(){

                            $(this).removeClass("left-button");
                            $(this).removeClass("right-button");

                    });
                    $('.internal'+first).addClass("left-button")
                    $('.internal'+third).addClass("right-button");
             }



            </script>
```

Something like this
[image]

Comment: how's this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/owWGzO

Comment: after a couple of right clicks ... it stops working

Comment: Please see the updated question with the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in future seeking a solution to this. Please have a look at this page https://gist.github.com/tim-reynolds/3019761

```
var out = $('.center'); //Outer Div containing all the child elements
var tar = $('#internal-target')); //Identifier of the target element, theone 
                                 that needs to be centered.
 var x = out.width();
 var y = tar.outerWidth(true);
 var z = tar.index();
 var q = 0;
 var m = out.find('.internal'); 
 //Just need to add up the width of all the elements before our target. 
 for(var i = 0; i < z; i++){
  q+= $(m[i]).outerWidth(true);
   } out.animate({
        scrollLeft: Math.max(0, q - (x - y)/2)+"px"
      }, "fast");
```